# Pandas DataFrame add sum per id

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this:

```
idx total
1   5
1   10
1   2
2   10
2   10
2   55
```

And would like to create another column that sums and averages totals per id to get this:

```
idx total sum   avg
1   5     17    5.66
1   10    17    5.66
1   2     17    5.66
2   10    75    25
2   10    75    25
2   55    75    25
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually we should using `transform` , but since `transform` can not accept list like function with `groupby` object , we using `agg`+`reindex`

```
df.groupby('idx').total.agg(['sum','mean']).reindex(df.idx).reset_index()
Out[64]: 
   idx  sum       mean
0    1   17   5.666667
1    1   17   5.666667
2    1   17   5.666667
3    2   75  25.000000
4    2   75  25.000000
5    2   75  25.000000

#df.groupby('idx').total.agg(['sum','mean']).reindex(df.idx).reset_index().assign(Todat=df.total.values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` with `agg` then `merge`:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('idx')['total']
           .agg(['sum','mean']), 
         left_on='idx', 
         right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   idx  total  sum       mean
0    1      5   17   5.666667
1    1     10   17   5.666667
2    1      2   17   5.666667
3    2     10   75  25.000000
4    2     10   75  25.000000
5    2     55   75  25.000000
```